# input selector with style attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am selecting an input type using jQuery with some conditions

```
var inputs = $(this).parents('form').find(
      ':input[type="text"]:enabled:visible:not("disabled"),textarea');
```

For some reason, I am using a style attribute for the input type.

```
<input type="text" style=" visibility:hidden"/>
```

How can I ignore the style `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: just remove `visible` from `var inputs =     $(this).parents('form').find(':input[type="text"]:enabled:not("disabled"),textarea');`

Comment: @champ,we got a solution using filter   'var inputs = $(this).parents('form').find(':input[type="text"]:enabled:visible:not("disabled"),textarea').filter(function() {
   return !($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none');
});'

Comment: ok sorry got confused one of my class mate name was same as yours :)

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to use "filter" function

```
inputs = inputs.filter(function(){
    return (!$(this).attr('style')); // if you want to exclude elements having style attribute set
});
```